# Prove that $n$ degrees of freedom leads to $n$ normal modes

Tags: oscillators, degrees-of-freedom, coupled-oscillators, linearized-theory, normal-modes

I have probably missed that during my studies. I intuitively know (but then I might be wrong in some detail, that's why I am asking), that $n$ degrees of freedom in oscillating system leads to $n$ eigenmodes. E.g. simple harmonic oscillator: 1 eigenmode, double pendulum: 2 eigenmodes, oscillating string: infinite number etc.

- Am I right (including special cases)?
- What is the proof of that?
- Bonus: Could it be made by physical reasoning? Just-math-based proof would be simple.

Comment: FWIW, a free particle has no normal modes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation that dictates the behavior of mechanical systems such as oscillators is Newton's Second Law. It is a second order differential equation, and in the case of oscillators it is linear and has the general form

$$\ddot{\vec{x}} = A\vec{x} .$$

This means that for each degree of freedom you have, another coordinate will be assigned to it and the matrix $A$ in the equation above will increase by one row and one column. If you assume this matrix is non-singular, that is, that this differential equation has a complete solution, then $A$ will have the same number of eigenvectors as the dimension of the space.

I think this is at the same time physically and mathematically intuitive.